# Does hyperledger composer support multi-thread?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

Hyperledger composer supports multi-users mode, so does it run this mode in multi threads or in multi processes, or just in asynchronous mode?

I try to run two client(two threads) for one card to access the composer rest server to proposal two tx at the same time, but it is offen blocked.

Comment: Are you doing all this for educational purposes ?

Comment: Yes,I want to study the composer even if it is deprecated, I try to get some useful info to build a midware which may be a little like composer but more simplified.Would you give some advise?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you weren't trying to use composer outside of an educational role. Unfortunately I think that the composer community has now disappeared so the chances of getting answers to questions now is very slim.
With regard to your question, Composer rest server is a standard rest server so requests will be processed as received and responses returned when there are responses. One request will not block another request in the rest server itself.

Comment: @david_k Thanks for your reply, would you give some advise on how to choose a rest server framework ?Also if there are design docs for composer? I think composer is a very good project, it is deprecated for technical reason or lack of support?